# Where can I look up my update history?

Tags: apt, updates

Is there a place where I can look what updates I've installed?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You can read the `history.log` file in `/var/log/apt`.

Eg. `less /var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: Worth noting that there may be older history files in that folder, not just `/var/log/apt/history.log`.  Maybe something like `/var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz`

Comment: Still working even on Bionic. Just in case someone's afraid because of the response's age.

Comment: To read and filter rotated logs: `zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.* | perl -00 -ne 'print if /\ninstall/i'` ([with `-00`](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_perl_oneliners/record-separators.html) each paragraphs is a record)

Comment: Terminal log `/var/log/opt/term.log` could also be useful if you need to figure out what happened during the installation.

Answer (score 48):

In 10.10, *Ubuntu Software Center* has a list of all the updates you have downloaded in the past.

[image]

Comment: +1 This answer works on more recent versions too.

Comment: @JamesBradbury This option is gone from Ubuntu 16.04 on

Answer (score 29):

/var/log/apt contains a history of package installations. However, by default, it is managed by `logrotate` which compresses and ages out old entries.

Comment: So is this the best place for me to check history on Ubuntu Server?

Comment: You can search and filter [with `zcat`/`zgrep`/`zless`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history#comment2297404_116067)

Answer (score 23):

As an alternative to lgarzo's answer, you can `grep` what you are interested in from `/var/log/dpkg.log`. E.g., if you want to see everything you installed or upgraded yesterday, you could run:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "^2012-03-25.*\ installed\ "
```

One thing to note: this will also list manually installed packages (`sudo dpkg -i ...`), which won't show up in apt's history.

Even better use zgrep if it's installed so you can find lines in gzipped files as well

```
zgrep "^2012-03-25.*\ installed\ " /var/log/dpkg.log*
```

Answer (score 21):

On 10.04 Click (System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager > File > History)

Comment: All I get is a list of packages that I installed via Synaptic, it doesn't show all the packages I updated via Update Manager.

Answer (score 11):

It's now possible to do this through the software center as well! Go to History and you can display all of your updates and installations.

[image: Software Center History]

Comment: I suppose it is 10.10 ?

Comment: Sure is. I don't think this was available in previous distributions...

Answer (score 4):

It became useful for us to have a slightly more easy and accurate answer to the question "when was the last time we patched this thing?".  So I put this together.  I tested it on 12.04 and 14.04 and 16.04.  It returns reasonably accurate answers for that question.
Note: "reasonably accurate" probably isn't "completely accurate".
Note: "for that question"  only.

sample output:

```
xenial% 9: ./linuxpatchdate 
2016-07-19 54
2017-02-24 363
2017-03-08 7
2017-03-09 2
```

subroutines and program:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

#------------------ subroutines --------------------

sub parseRecord {
    my $sdate = "";
    my $useful = 0;
    my $packages = 0;
    my @ptmp;
    while (my $recordLine = shift() ) {

       if ($recordLine =~ m/^Start-Date: ([\d\-]*).*/) {
          $sdate = $1;
       }
       elsif ($recordLine =~ m/^Commandline:.*upgrade/) {
          $useful = 1;
       }
       elsif ($recordLine =~ m/^Install: (.*)/) {
          $recordLine =~ s/\([^\)]*\)//g;
          @ptmp = split(/,/,$recordLine);
          $packages = $packages + $#ptmp + 1;
       }
       elsif ($recordLine =~ m/^Upgrade: (.*)/) {
          $recordLine =~ s/\([^\)]*\)//g;
          @ptmp = split(/,/,$recordLine);
          $packages = $packages + $#ptmp + 1;
       }
    }



    if ($useful) {
       return ($sdate,$packages);
    }
    else {
       return ("0",0);
    }
}


#------------------ main program --------------------

@lines = split(/\n/,`/bin/zcat -f /var/log/apt/history.log  /var/log/apt/history*gz`);
my %patchHash;
my $line;
my @inputLines;
my $pushDate = "";
my $pushNum = "";

foreach $line (@lines) {
    # all records separated by blank lines
    if ($line !~ /./) {
       # no-op
    }
    elsif ($line =~ m/^Start-Date: ([\d\-]*).*/) {
       @inputLines = ();
       push (@inputLines, $line);
    }
    elsif ($line =~ m/^End-Date: ([\d\-]*).*/) {
       ($pushDate, $pushNum) = parseRecord(@inputLines);
       if ($pushNum != 0) {
          $patchHash{$pushDate} += $pushNum;
       }
    }
    else {
       push (@inputLines, $line);
    }
}

foreach $pushDate (sort(keys(%patchHash))) {
   print "$pushDate $patchHash{$pushDate}\n";
}
```