# Compiz runs almost at 100% and the system is slow, what can I do?

Tags: nvidia, compiz

My system became very slow out of the sudden, yesterday Compiz was running extremely smooth, today it started working very slow and slowing the computer.

What I've done so far was to resize my swap partition to 6 gigabytes (my computer has 3 gigabytes of RAM), before it was on 5.1 gigabytes, so I though that was the reason of this but still not.

Also I tested running only metacity by running `metacity --replace` and also with Mutter. With metacity works really great no problem but, in the other hand, with mutter the computer works slower than running compiz instead.

I am using the Nvidia driver version 173.14.28 and my X Server version as reports the NVidia X Server Settings is the 11.0.

My Linux kernel running on this computer is 2.6.35-25-generic and my ubuntu version is 10.10.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To narrow down the likely sources of problems, create a new user (System/Administration/Users and Groups) and log in as that new user. If it works, the original problem is related to your user configuration - your compiz settings, perhaps. If it's still broken, it's a system-wide problem and presumably related to an update or something else that changed in the system. You could [check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history) what updates, if any, you installed lately.

Comment: I checked for the updates, actually I found that the NVidia driver 185 was available but inactive by unknown reasons. I enabled it and reinstalled compiz but now I am getting this: **compiz (video) - Warn: No 8 bit GLX pixmap format, disabling YV12 image format**  Is the same with any other user I create on the computer. BTW, when compiz runs the computer doesn't draw anything on the screen, I have to press ALT+F2 to launch metacity --replace...

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not using 10.10 and neither same version of kernel, but during those days when I was using 9.10 with nVidia driver and Compiz on, I do have this issue before.

What I did was I choose to run nVidia with Vdpau using the following PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~nvidia-vdpau/+archive/ppa

Make sure you backup all data before trying this. Use at own risk.

Comment: Given that the system used to work fine some time ago, it doesn't seem a good idea to randomly change something unrelated, like trying a different video driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some times ago and in my case it was related to compiz version and video driver version. Are you sure you didn't updated one or the other ?

You could also try to start compiz from a terminal (just type `compiz`), that may show you some warning message that is invisible otherwise. In my case there was such message (sorry I can't exactly remember what it said) and the problem was indeed related to that.

Comment: Hi, sorry to answer until today, this is what I am getting in this case:

`libccs: dlopen: /usr/lib/compizconfig/backends/libgconf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't find a perfect decorator match; trying all decorators
Found no decorator to start`

The last time I uninstalled Compiz from the computer and today I reinstalled it to test it and now this is what I am getting, I will try with another user and see if I get the same

Comment: @Heiner Valverde: The first message is probably there because compizconfig-backend-gconf package is not installed. You may try to install it and see if it helps (not sure it's related to you 100% CPU problem).

Comment: well actually the package compiz was not installed, so I installed and the message was gone but now I am getting this: **compiz (video) - Warn: No 8 bit GLX pixmap format, disabling YV12 image format**, compiz doesn't draw anything on the screen and metacity is also now having problems to start when Ubuntu starts. Now I am running the lastest NVidia driver for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I today had this problem with compiz taking up all cpu resources and came to the conclusion that the reason was that I just installed gnome-panel (just gnome-panel without any dependencies/suggested applications). I uninstalled gnome-panel and that fixed the issue.