# Does the Update Manager have a log?

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I look up my update history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history)

If Update Manager has a log of updates installed, where can I find it? Alternatively, is there a list of these online somewhere?

Comment: As far as I know, it would only be online if you upload/sync it somewhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

/var/log/apt/history.log

Just open in your favorite file viewer/editor.

Comment: `/var/log/apt/term.log` may also be useful: it contains the terminal output of the update command and may have additional information / error messages.