# How can I access my package update history from the command line?

Tags: command-line, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I look up my update history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history)

In Synaptic Package Manager and Ubuntu Software Centre I can view a history of recent package updates. How can I do the same from the command line?