# Sound Menu gone missing after PulseAudio 3.0 install

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Yesterday i was trying to minimize the lag when streaming music from my Ubuntu 12.10 laptop to my pulseaudio server on my raspberry pi, by installing pulseaudio 3.0 on the raspberry pi and then again on my 12.10 laptop. Unfortunately i did not see what i uninstalled when i installed pulseaudio client 3.0 via 13.04 repository, and after the install and reboot i am missing my sound menu from systray and when i click on sound in gnome control center nothing happens. What did i uninstall that i should not have?

Comment: See what was removed from your [update history](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history). Which ppa did you use?

Comment: Sorry, just changed that. I used the 13.04 repositories. And i did not make sudo apt-get upgrade. I just used sudo apt-get install pulseaudio... No info in update history...