# How to know last time `apt-get update` was executed?

Tags: apt, updates, logs

I know that the command to update the repository lists is:

```
apt-get update
```

How to check if it has been executed today or in the last 24 hours?

I do not know if I should check some file timestamp. Or issue another `apt` command. Or use `dpkg` utility.

Could not find something useful at man pages.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can check your command history in terminal :

```
history | grep 'apt update'
```

To check it by time :

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T " history | grep '[a]pt update'
```

(The `[a]` part of the regular expression only matches the letter `a` but has the effect to not match itself when grepping in the history.)

[image: Terminal history with timestamp]

Comment: It is `history | grep 'apt-get update'` :)

Comment: try the updated answer and enjoy it my friend

Comment: @Lucio It will not show the time of execution of a command. It just puts a timestamp to the commands. See all other commands. You can see all have same time. Is it not so?

Comment: @souravc No it will show each command by time excuted

Comment: @nux have you checked by yourself, plz try `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T" && history | head`. It puts smae time for all the commands that was executed earlier of using `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T"`

Comment: check the picture man

Comment: So should complemnt it with cut to enable a time expression comparison?

Comment: @souravc is right. This won't work on its own. If the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is not set in `.bashrc` then this command will only have correct timestamps for the commands which were actually executed from the **current shell session**. For all the other commands which is not from the current session the timestamp will only show the modification timestamp of the `~/.bash_history` file. It can't show the timestamps for commands from other sessions as those timestamps are not saved in the `~/.bash_history` file. It can show timestamps for the current session because those stamps are still in the memory.

Comment: This does not always work. E.g. when some other user ran `apt` or when your `.bash_history` has been trimmed.

Comment: This is a terribly wrong answer.  It doesn't account for unattended upgrades, plus if you're someone like me who always has 4-5 terminals open, the history only gets saved when they exit (by default), so you would have to check all of them.

Comment: Echoing what everyone has already said, that won't work if apt has been updated by a script, if you're not looking at the right history, if the history has been trimmed, or if another user has done the update. That's really not reliable enough to solve the general case.

Answer (score 76):

Check the time stamp of `/var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp`.

```bsh
$ ls -l /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 25 01:41 /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp
```

Here the time is `Jan 25 01:41` when `apt-get` last executed. To get the time only, use the following command in terminal,

```bsh
$ ls -l /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp | awk '{print $6" "$7" "$8}'
Jan 25 01:41
```

It is the best place to check the last update time. If you found `/var/lib/apt/periodic/` to be empty you can try,

```bsh
ls -l /var/log/apt/history.log
```

**Update**

It is found that due to some reasons above files `update-success-stamp` or `history.log` remain unavailable in some systems. There is a new [proposal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410247/how-to-know-last-time-apt-get-was-executed/410259?noredirect=1#comment563122_410259) from [derobert](https://askubuntu.com/users/1565/derobert)  to look into the file `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin`.

[`pkgcache.bin`](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?21911-pkgcache-bin) is Apt's memory mapped package cache location. It get renewed after each update. So it is the perfect candidate to know the last time when `apt` was updated.

One can use the following command to know the exact time,

```
ls -l /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin | cut -d' ' -f6,7,8
```

or

```
stat /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin
```

Comment: my `/var/lib/apt/periodic/` directory is empty

Comment: My directory is also empty. Debian 7.3 wheezy.

Comment: Mine history file does not log apt update commands. So I could not find a line where to extract the timestamp. I could find an apt-get upgrade line only.

Comment: A better backup location would be `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin`. Also, please don't parse the output of `ls`; use `stat` instead. Keep in mind that `ls` output depends on locale, depends on age of file, etc. (Also, I think you only get the first file you suggest if you have update-notifier-common installed)

Comment: @souravc ping on updating the answer—or would you like me to write up my own answer instead?

Comment: @derobert very sorry I completely forgot. I am updating your addition. You are always welcome to write your own answer.

Comment: Checking pkgcache.bin is the only reliable way to see if the 'update' command was run. Update won't log anything into history but it will regenerate the cache.

Comment: It seems `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` is also touched on package installation, so it's not a reliable way to check for the last `apt-get update` run.

Comment: As [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/505341/52860) points out, if you want to compare it programmatically in a shell script, you'll probably want to use `stat` with `-c %Y` for seconds since the epoch.

Comment: ...and I just discovered that a Debian 8 system where `apt-get clean` has been run recently will have no `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin`. I'm going to try using the mtime from `/var/lib/apt/lists` instead, since that seems to be the raw, non-cached data which `apt-get update` actually manipulates.

Comment: Installing `update-notifier-common` on 16.04 provided `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/15update-stamp` which contains the config to touch `/var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp` after successful update.  Running `apt-get update` after installing update-notifier-common does indeed create the update-success-stamp file.

Answer (score 7):

I use `/var/cache/apt` to determine if I need to run `apt-get update`. By default, if the difference between the current time and cache time of `/var/cache/apt` is less than 24 hr, I don't need to run `apt-get update`. The default update interval can be overridden by passing a number to function `runAptGetUpdate()`

```
function trimString()
{
    local -r string="${1}"

    sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/ *$//g' <<< "${string}"
}

function isEmptyString()
{
    local -r string="${1}"

    if [[ "$(trimString "${string}")" = '' ]]
    then
        echo 'true'
    else
        echo 'false'
    fi
}

function info()
{
    local -r message="${1}"

    echo -e "\033[1;36m${message}\033[0m" 2>&1
}

function getLastAptGetUpdate()
{
    local aptDate="$(stat -c %Y '/var/cache/apt')"
    local nowDate="$(date +'%s')"

    echo $((nowDate - aptDate))
}

function runAptGetUpdate()
{
    local updateInterval="${1}"

    local lastAptGetUpdate="$(getLastAptGetUpdate)"

    if [[ "$(isEmptyString "${updateInterval}")" = 'true' ]]
    then
        # Default To 24 hours
        updateInterval="$((24 * 60 * 60))"
    fi

    if [[ "${lastAptGetUpdate}" -gt "${updateInterval}" ]]
    then
        info "apt-get update"
        apt-get update -m
    else
        local lastUpdate="$(date -u -d @"${lastAptGetUpdate}" +'%-Hh %-Mm %-Ss')"

        info "\nSkip apt-get update because its last run was '${lastUpdate}' ago"
    fi
}
```

Sample Output:

```
<root@ubuntu><~/ubuntu-cookbooks/libraries>
# runAptGetUpdate 

Skip apt-get update because its last run was '0h 37m 43s' ago
```

I extracted these functions from my personal github: https://github.com/gdbtek/ubuntu-cookbooks/blob/master/libraries/util.bash

Answer (score 5):

Combining @ssokolow's last comment with the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005083/7581), this command will run `apt-get update` if it hasn't run in the last 7 days:

```
[ -z "$(find -H /var/lib/apt/lists -maxdepth 0 -mtime -7)" ] && sudo apt-get update
```

Explanation:

- `-mtime -7` finds files that have a change time in the last 7 days. You can use `-mmin` if you care about shorter times.
- `-maxdepth 0` ensures find won't go into the contents of the directory.
- `-H` dereferences `/var/lib/apt/lists` if it's a soft link
- If for some reason `find` fails, then the command would run. This seems to me like the safe default. If you want to flip the default, use `-n` in the test and `-mtime +7` in the find command.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is interested, this is the way [Ansible does it](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/12734fa21c08a0ce8c84e533abdc560db2eb1955/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py#L1012-L1022):

```py
APT_UPDATE_SUCCESS_STAMP_PATH = "/var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp"
APT_LISTS_PATH = "/var/lib/apt/lists"

#
# [...]
#

def get_cache_mtime():
    """Return mtime of a valid apt cache file.
    Stat the apt cache file and if no cache file is found return 0
    :returns: ``int``
    """
    cache_time = 0
    if os.path.exists(APT_UPDATE_SUCCESS_STAMP_PATH):
        cache_time = os.stat(APT_UPDATE_SUCCESS_STAMP_PATH).st_mtime
    elif os.path.exists(APT_LISTS_PATH):
        cache_time = os.stat(APT_LISTS_PATH).st_mtime
    return cache_time
```

Answer (score 3):

```
LAST_UPDATED=$( stat --format="%X" /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin )
UNIX_TIME=$( date +%s )
TIME_DIFF=$(( UNIX_TIME - LAST_UPDATED ))

if [[ "${TIME_DIFF}" -gt 43200 ]]
then
  # It's been 12 hours since apt-get update was ran.
fi
```

Comment: You might just use: `[ "$(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin) ))" -gt 43200 ] && echo Time to go!`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command to show last time it was accessed ie. running `apt-get update` also last time it was actually updated:

```
stat  /var/cache/apt/ | grep -i -e access -e modify
```

Note if the times are different there may not have been an update available. Since I have my updates and upgrades running by `crontab` at specific times I can tell if my updates ran or not.

Answer (score 1):

You may also interested about the file:

```
/var/log/apt/term.log
```

Open it with *less* or *cat* as *root*.

Comment: This is a sensible place to check for logs of actions apt has performed on the package database, but afaik the poster wants to know about `apt-get update`, and that is obviously not logged.

Answer (score 1):

For `apt` specifically, I recommend [this one-liner](https://askubuntu.com/a/904259/118084) by @itsadok:

```
[ -z "$(find -H /var/lib/apt/lists -maxdepth 0 -mtime -7)" ] && sudo apt-get update
```

However If you want a more portable "*update package manager **at least** every x days*" semantics, you can simply touch a temp file when you update.

For example:

```
APT_UPDATED="/tmp/apt-update-tstamp"

# Delete temp file created >1 day ago
find "$APT_UPDATED" -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \; 2>/dev/null

# Update apt if needed
if [ ! -f "$APT_UPDATED" ]; then
  if apt-get update; then
    touch "$APT_UPDATED"
  fi
fi
```

This should work in most scenarios since:

- More updates wont hurt you (except time)
- Doesn't rely on any apt internals (could expand to pkg, yum, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I just posted an answer to this question on following topic

[Where can I look up my update history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history)

The answer may be less appropriate for this topic, as it specifically looks for "apt-get upgrade".  Here's sample output.

```
xenial% 9: ./linuxpatchdate 
2016-07-19 54
2017-02-24 363
2017-03-08 7
2017-03-09 2
```

See the other topic for source code and more explanation.

Comment: It looked to me like your code looked for upgrade, not update. For example, I just ran "apt-get update" (the subject of this question) on my Ubuntu 16.04 and not one iota of change appears in /var/log/apt, implying that scanning anything in that directory will be of no use in answer this particular question.

Comment: You're totally right.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've changed my answer to reflect that.  We were looking for the last date updates were applied to the machine, rather than updates being just downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

This command will work:

```
stat -c %y /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu `21.10` You can grep the `history.log` like this:

```
grep -i 'Start-Date' /var/log/apt/history.log | tail -n1
Start-Date: 2022-03-07  11:09:14
```

This command will return the very last date of the `apt update` command.

Answer (score 0):

The last-modified timestamp of `/var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp` is used to indicate the last time `apt-get update` was successfully run.

So to check if it's been more than 24 hours since we last ran `apt-get update`, use the following in Bash:

```bash
last_update=`stat -c %Y /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp`
if [ $((`date +%s`-$last_update)) -gt $((24*60*60)) ]; then
  ...
fi
```

Explanation:

- `stat -c %Y /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp` gets the mtime timestamp (in seconds since Epoch) of the file.
- `date +%s` gets the current time (in seconds since Epoch).
- `` $((`date +%s`-$last_update)) `` calculates the difference, that is the number of seconds since the last successful `apt-get update`.
- `[ ... -gt $((24*60*60)) ]` checks if this number is greater than the number of seconds in a day.