# Calling apt-get -y update in a bash script: once or multiple times?

Tags: apt, bash, package-management

I am writing a bash script to install a number of packages. Do I need to call `apt-get -y update` each time before I call `apt-get install <package_name>`? Or is it enough to call `apt-get -y update` once at the beginning of the script?

If it needs to be called multiple times, could you explain why?

Comment: One time would be enough

Comment: And you can put your packages all on one line

Comment: See [What does "sudo apt-get update" do?](//askubuntu.com/q/222348)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `apt-get -y update` if:

1. It has not been called for a long time (e.g. in the last 24h)
2. If the list of repositories has changed since the last update

For the first point: obviously in a simple case it would be sufficient to call update just once at the beginning. In a more complicated script it may be useful to call an internal update procedure before each call to `apt-get -y install` and inside of this internal procedure you would automatically detect if the last update was run a long time ago and needs to be executed. See [How to know last time `apt-get update` was executed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410247/how-to-know-last-time-apt-get-update-was-executedapt-get)

For the second point: If you have a more complicated scenario and your script may possibly add repositories between the calls to install the packages, you may want to check the last modification dates of

- `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

in order to determine if new repositories were added after the last call of  `apt-get update`, and if it needs to be called again in that case.

Comment: Some install processes require `apt-get update` to be called in order to terminate properly. For example, the last three steps for installing Phusion Passenger are: `sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger xenial main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'` **`sudo apt-get update`** and finally `sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger`. Without `apt-get update`, the package is not correctly installed.