# How do I find out when debian packages were last updated?

Tags: 10.04, software-installation, debian-installer

I access an ubuntu 10.04LTS server that is administered by someone else, I have a feeling that it hasn't been getting updates/upgrades recently.

Is there a way to check on the command line when updates were last taken, without sudo privileges?

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history

Comment: @fossfreedom ...not exactly, he is asking unprivileged and CLI solutions.

Comment: Several answers already there that doesnt require privilege and are also CLI based.

Comment: @fossfreedom Yep, you're right. Missed some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stat -c %y /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp` to find last update date.

It will give the date of last `apt-get update`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the version of some critical package:

```
% dpkg -l linux-generic

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  linux-generic  3.11.0.17.18 i386         Complete Generic Linux kernel and
```

and compare with up-to-date system (the example is from 13.10).

The file `/var/log/apt/history.log` is normally readable by all, so it can help (but its content is log-rotated, so if the last update is old, it may well be empty; you can search the various `/var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz` for hints).