# Daily Ubuntu base update

Tags: update-manager, release-management

I am getting Ubuntu base update almost every day. This seems strange to me. What am I missing?

(I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you see if the updates are indeed in your history: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history ? Maybe it will give a clue as to the version of each update and if the same one keeps getting run.

Answer (score 13):

**Ubuntu base** is a group for the tools and services and core parts of Ubuntu and the following applies equally to any software installed.

It's normal to have Ubuntu base updates more often. In Linux, security flaws are found much easier when they exist due to the code being open. Then the patch is immediately put upstream and onto your computer through the package update.

Whereas in a closed source system, often such flaws aren't found until exploitation. Its just a matter of when the security flaw is found, not the existence itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare your configuration against the list of updates [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_logs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&commit=Filter&head_only=true&noppa=1&vals=trusty&type=dists&levels%5Bsecurity%5D=1). The list seems quite in sync with [the official reports](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/trusty/). Needles to say, to get the right picture, don't forget to apply the proper filtering corresponding to your PPAs, in case it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers say, this seems normal. If the frequent update reminders bothers you, you can set up [automatic security updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates).

Answer (score -1):

If it gets annoying you could change Security Updates in your update setting to how long you want. After that time it would show you if a new update has come.

Comment: This isn't recommended as you won't receive important security updates as often unless you manually refresh more.