# Update gone wrong .. I think

Tags: system, crash

I just did the latest up date , when I turned on my Acer laptop this morning it started spazzing , it's asking for my login which I have no idea about but I know my password just not login , it says it after it first starts with lots of writing 
Can anybody help me out please ?

Answer (score 3):

Your login password is the same as your user password.

1. At the screen with a lot of writing where your boot has stopped, open a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. After you have logged in in the console type:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm start # Ubuntu 14.10 and earlier
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo systemctl start graphical.target # Ubuntu 15.04 and later
   ```

   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up your default login screen and then login to your Ubuntu desktop environment as usual. If have a different desktop environment than the default Ubuntu Unity desktop environment, please comment so that I can change the command in Step 4.

After you have logged in to Ubuntu as usual, please check [Where can I look up my update history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history) which tells you how to check your recent update history. Please provide information about what were the packages in your latest update, so that I can tell you how to undo the latest update.

Answer (score 2):

- Enter you username in the login box.
- If you do not know your username boot using a live CD (or if you are dual booting with Windows then use ext2fsd).
- Open file browser and mount Ubuntu drive.
- Go to home.
- There must be a folder. The name of the folder is your username.
- Reboot and login to Ubuntu.
- Now open terminal, type in `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lights
- Use arrow keys and select lightdm and press enter.

Note If you use Gnome replace lightdm with gdm3.

Comment: Good suggestion on recovering a forgotten username. ;-)

Comment: Nice method to use!