# Boot screen not displaying correctly after updating 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

Hi I'm having an issue with the boot screen which only seems to be displaying a white font on a purple background and a dotted progress bar.

It happened when I installed some updates after booting in to Ubuntu.

I'm currently using ubuntu on a HP notebook

Here is what I can see when booting up. [Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ajZf.jpg)

Help appreciated.

Comment: That photo adds nothing to the question. What were the updates you installed?

Comment: I installed updates via the software updater application I can't for sure tell you what updates I have installer since there was a lot.

Comment: Look at this question and its answers. It explains where to find the log of what the update did. https://askubuntu.com/questions/14328/where-can-i-look-up-my-update-history