# My touchpad doesn't work perfectly after upgrade of Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, touchpad, bug-reporting

I used all the options on my touchpad (two fingers to scroll the page, two fingers to direct-click, etc) and after I updated Ubuntu today, it just stopped. The touchpad works, but only normal click and double click; the other options are somehow no longer available.
Before, in Settings, when I went to the touchpad section, there were several options to configure regarding its features, but now when I open it, I see that there is almost nothing, as if there was a setback.

(Some time ago, I had messed up with grub and something similar had happened, but I managed to edit the file and the touchpad was back to normal, but when my PC started up, several codes appeared on the screen instead of the ubuntu welcome screen , but nothing that hindered the use of the notebook. Then today, when I turned on the pc, I saw that the codes were no longer showing, but the Ubuntu welcome screen; and coincidentally my touchpad was not working well either. I assumed it was a grub issue, as it probably should have been modified when upgrading. So I created a live usb to reinstall grub [the touchpad worked perfectly in live usb], and after reinstalling grub, I turned on the pc and nothing changed ).

Please help me! [I'm sending a print of how the touchpad part of the settings is doing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjQuK.png)
And forgive my english too, I don't speak english.

Edit1: in response of @pablo Bianchi

```
➜ xinput list 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]


➜ xinput list-props 13
Device 'ImPS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse':
    Device Enabled (179):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (181): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (316):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (317):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (318):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (319):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (320):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (321): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (322): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (323):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (324):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (325): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (326): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (327):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (328):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (329):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (330): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (331): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (301): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (302):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (303):    0, 0
    Device Node (304):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (305):    2, 5
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (332):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (333):   1
```

Comment: You update from what version to what version? Get your touchpad ID from `xpinput list` and paste the output of `xinput list-props ID`. Also could be useful `cat /proc/bus/input/devices | perl -00 -ne 'print if /touchpad/i'`. Did you found something on `journalctl -p warning`?

Comment: @PabloBianchi first, thanks for help me. I edited the post with the information you asked for (I don't know if this is how I should have posted it, I'm new to the forum).
The command "cat /proc/bus/input/devices | perl -00 -ne 'print if /touchpad/i'" returned nothing, and the "journalctl -p warning" returned A LOT. How can I show it here?
And by the way, I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, and the update was one of the daily updates.

Comment: You added the properties of the mouse, and that info doesn't show any touchpad. "managed to edit the file": what file? About journalctll: You should read it for suspicious warnings/errors. Also [read upgrade package history](https://askubuntu.com/a/116067/349837). Try also booting with a live distro, if that way everything works.

Comment: @PabloBianchi That's the problem: it's recognizing it as a mouse by the looks of it! I'm not using any mouse, just the touchpad.
And the file I talked about was "grub", but it doesn't seem to be a grub problem now.
And yes, it works perfectly in a live distro!

Comment: @PabloBianchi Reading the "journalctl -p warning" I found many things, and I also realized that it's not just the touchpad, my bluetooth is also giving an error! I created a [repository on github](https://github.com/thiagodeev/bugss) to send some prints and also a copy of "journalctl -p warning" in .txt format; the file name is "dump-of-journalctl.txt".
Please keep helping me! You're the only one

Comment: If on a live distro works fine probably the easiest way is to start from scratch, a fresh install